# VB.NET nullReferenceException Unhandled

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I can't add question(txtQuestion.Text) to the dataGridView  but if you add the same question it works and shows MessageBox.Show("You can't enter the same question."). Adding data is my only problem.

```
Dim qID As String
        rnd.Next(0, 99999)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In UsersDBDataGridView.Rows
            If txtQuestion.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString Then '<-- NullReferenceException was unahandled.
                MessageBox.Show("You cant enter the same Question.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                valid = True
                Exit For
            Else
                valid = False
            End If
        Next
        If cbxDifficulty.Text = "Easy" Then
            diff = "E"
            diffValue = 5
        ElseIf cbxDifficulty.Text = "Average" Then
            diff = "A"
            diffValue = 10
        ElseIf cbxDifficulty.Text = "Difficult" Then
            diff = "D"
            diffValue = 20
        End If
        qID = diff & "-" & Date.Now.Date.ToString("ddMMMyyyy").ToUpper & "-" & rnd.ToString("00000")
        If valid = False Then
            Me.UsersDBTableAdapter.Add(qID, txtQuestion.Text, txtAnswer.Text, diffValue)
            Me.UsersDBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UsersDBDataSet.UsersDB)
        End If
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a null check to your `If`-statement for the `Value` property.

```
If row.Cells(1).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso txtQuestion.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString Then
```

And I'd just like to point out: There's ***nothing wrong*** with using the `=` operator to compare strings.

Infact, [**the equality operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) calls [**`String.Equals()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform the comparison:

> The operator, in turn, calls the static Equals(String, String) method, which performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.